# Hilbert subspace

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let be $H$ Hilbert space and $M\subset H$. $M=M^{\perp\perp}$ if and only if $M$ subspace of $H$.

Does anyone know to prove this?

Comment: I believe it should be "if and only if $M$ is a _closed_ subspace of $H$", right?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** Let $M \subset H$ be a subset.

- Show that $M^{\perp}$ is a vector space.
- If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $M^{\perp}$ converging to some $x \in H$, show that $x \in M^{\perp}$. Therefore, $M^{\perp}$ is closed.
- Deduce that if $M=M^{\perp \perp}$ then $M$ is a closed subvector space.

For the converse, let $M \subset H$ be a closed subvector space.

- Show that $M \subset M^{\perp \perp}$.
- By contraddiction, suppose that $M \subsetneq M^{\perp \perp}$. Use [Hahn-Banach separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem) and [Riesz representation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem#The_Hilbert_space_representation_theorem) to find $x_0 \in M^{\perp \perp} \backslash M$ and $v \in H$ such that $\langle x,v \rangle < \langle x_0,v \rangle$ for any $x \in M$. Deduce that $v \in M^{\perp}$ and find a contradiction.

Comment: Problem is how to show this: if $M=M^{\perp\perp}$ then $M $ subspace of $H$.

Comment: If $A^{\perp}$ is a subvector space for any set $A$, then $M^{\perp \perp}$ is a subvector space since $M^{\perp \perp}=(M^{\perp})^{\perp}$.

Comment: I'm working on the same problem right now and I'm stuck with this bit: Given that $M$ is a subspace with $M^{\perp \perp}=M$, how can I show that $M$ is closed, i.e. $M^{\perp \perp}=M=\overline{M}$?

Comment: @Amarus: I added some details.